# How can i concatenate the id and the # and put it in the href tag? This code is not working for me

Tags: php, concatenation

```
$temporaryID = $row->id; //data row ID from table
$concat = "#".$temporaryID; //concatenate it for href

if($x % 2==1){
    echo '<li class="featuredNews-li" href="$concat" data-toggle="tab">';
 }
?>
```

Trying to concatenate the # with the data id to put it the href tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the string in double quotes (and escape the ones inside of the string)

```
 echo "<li class=\"featuredNews-li\" href=\"$concat\" data-toggle=\"tab\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$temporaryID = $row->id;
$concat = "#".$temporaryID;

if($x % 2==1){
    echo '<li class="featuredNews-li" href="$concat" data-toggle="tab">';
 }
```

To:
eliminating `$concat`

```
$temporaryID = '#' . $row->id;
if($x & 1){
    echo "<li class=\"featuredNews-li\" href=\"$temporaryID\" data-toggle=\"tab\">";
 }
```

I prefer `$x & 1` rather than `$x % 2==1` because the AND function is a single micro instruction. Your method is a math function and comparison.

But that is here nor there. Double quoted string with escaped double quote within the sting.